# CreateUserIdenityAsync returns "UserId not found" exception for custom IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm following along the [bitoftech tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/) about creating Identity and role based claims with JWT. My application user is a custom User table with int PK.

Currently, the GenerateUserIdentityAsync method just returns a weird `UserId not found` error. here's my code:

```
ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, "JWT");
```

and the implementation in `User` entity:

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User, int> manager, string authenticationType)
{
    //error on this line: CreateIdentityAsync throws error
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
    return userIdentity;
}
```

My UserManager class is defined like so:

```
public class AppUserManager : UserManager<User, int>
```

Weirdly enough, when I debug, the instance `this` in `GenerateIdentityAsync` does have a `UserId` property, but the base only has an `id` and I wonder if that is where it's erroring out? (it doesnt sound right)

I was looking at the [source code](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-rtm-140226/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/ClaimsIdentityFactory.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core) (line 80) but I can't figure out where the exception is being thrown.

The exact exception being thrown is:

```
 UserId not found. 
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: 
    System.InvalidOperationException: 
    UserId not found.
```

And [stack trace](http://pastebin.com/kTdbeLVk) isn't all that helpful (to me)

**How do I find out why / where the UserId is not available?**

---

Mode details:

My `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials()`:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] {"*"});

    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    User user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

    if (user == null) // this is NOT null
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The username or password is incorrect");
        return;
    }

    // this line fails
    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, "JWT"); 
    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);
    context.Validated(ticket);
}
```

And the `ApplicationUser` (which, in my case, is just `User`)

```
public partial class User : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{  
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Verify in your aspnet db if you have the correct column names (UserId instead of Id or vice versa). Also one possibility is of column type mismatch (uniqueidentifiers as against nvarchar(256)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you found out while debugging `IdentityUser` has an `Id` which in your case would represent the User's Id.

You need to remove the `UserId` from your `User` class, use the base `Id` from `IdentityUser` and rename the `UserId` column in your custom User table to `Id`.

Any properties you have in your `User` class needs to also have a matching column in your user table in the database. If not then you will get the same error for properties that do not match.

That would mean `Fullname`, `Address` and `ContactNumber` must have matching column names in the `AspNetUsers` table or else you will get the same error for those properties as well.

Comment: hi, made these changes in mine, but still hitting the same error; I'm now question if `UserId` is what I think it is, there is no inner exception, only stack trace but that's not of much help unfortunately. Your code above pulls user twice, which is not a problem if it worked, I could refactor later, but it's still throwing the exact same exception

Comment: @LocustHorde, I went back to the drawing board and rechecked your problem.  Using the additional information you provided I was able to recreate the same exception, Including the inner exception. `UserId` needs to be a valid column in the `AspNetUsers` Table. I think a previous commenter also indicated this as well.

Comment: Excellent! After your comment I noticed there were two `UserId` as well as `Id` columns in by table, and in my seed method I was just populating `UserId`, and the `Id` was zero. When I tried to login, for whatever reason the method kept throwing `UserId` is not found. Once I manually changed the zero to an integer, it started working okay! So I guess I have to remove `Id` and somehow tell Identity to use `UserId` instead...

Comment: Whoops, just saw your edit, let me follow that up, thanks!

Comment: @LocustHorde that would be correct. I'll check that as well and update my answer. Are you doing code first or connecting to an existing table?

Comment: Ok, the my answer it not completely wrong. lol. In my case I was connecting to an existing database. Unless you plan on rewriting the Identity framework to use the UserId, I would advise that you use the built in Id. Is the `UserId` a requirement?

Comment: No, it is not, I thought I'd follow the convention as other models use the NameId format, but, thanks your answer + comments definitely nailed the problem on it's head! I shall use Id for this one for now and save me some headache!

Comment: I'm not using EF, or IdentityUser, but directly using `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<Guid>` with my custom User class, and the same applies.  I had defined my Id property as UserId and was getting same error as OP when calling GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id).  Swapped UserId out for Id and its all good.

Answer (score 3):

You have both `UserId` and `Id` properties in your `User` class - `Id` is inherited from `IdentityUser`. The problem is that you probably configured `UserId` to be the primary key for `User`.

The exception you get is thrown in `ClaimsIdentityFactory.CreateAsync` method, on [line 97](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-rtm-140226/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/ClaimsIdentityFactory.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core) `UserManager.GetSecurityStampAsync`. As you can see, `user.Id` used for retrieving a security stamp.

If you look inside `UserManager.GetSecurityStampAsync` you will see that the exception you get is thrown exactly here:

```
public virtual async Task<string> GetSecurityStampAsync(TKey userId)
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    var securityStore = GetSecurityStore();
    var user = await FindByIdAsync(userId).WithCurrentCulture();
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Resources.UserIdNotFound,
            userId));
    }
    return await securityStore.GetSecurityStampAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();
}
```

Thus, remove `UserId` property from `User` class and start using `Id` (inherited from `IdentityUser`) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I faced exact same issue. After much of a head ache I could sort out the real problem. 
When you change  data type of the Id property of User class to string, a Guid().ToString() is assigned to the Id property in the constructor and the same value is saved to the database and Identity retrieves the user details using that value.

However, if you changed the data type of the Id property to int and did not provide a value for that property in the constructor, the Identity still tries to retrieve the User details by using the default int value (0) this causes throws the message "System.InvalidOperationException: UserId not found".

I solved this by retrieving the value from the database by command.ExecuteScalar() and assign the value to user.Id. 
Hope this will help some one facing similar problem.

Comment: Hi @vkuttyp, what constructor are you talking about? Thanks.

Comment: can you share a bit more details? where did you exactly set that user.Id ? thanks

Comment: Hi @chemitaxis, the constructor I mentioned is the IdentityUser class constructor.

Comment: Hi. The actual issue that I faced was not related to the question. My issue was coming from creating new user. So what I did was after inserting new user to the database retrieved the primary key from database and updated that to the user object.

Answer (score 2):

What does your ApplicationUser class look like?
What does this method look like in your application?

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context){}
```

Taiseer's comments about GrantResourceOwnerCredentials are:

> "we are building an identity for the logged in user, this identity
>   will contain all the roles and claims for the authenticated user"

I had to add the ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier to the ClaimsIdentity to resolve a similar issue. Here is the important part of my GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method:

```
ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

if (user == null)
{
    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
    return;
}

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()));
```

Comment: Hi, added both code blocks above; you're not using JWT?

Comment: I tried it with `DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie` and still the same error, I guess I can rule out JWT interfering with it at least for now

Comment: Correct, I was not using JWT.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error happened because I added another SignInManager inside the method Login in the Account Controller (following an example of adding a role). It was executing SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync and SignInManager.SignInAsync in the same method and this calls GenerateUserIdentityAsync(...) in ApplicationUser twice, for which the first one succeeded and the second one gave me the exception "UserId" Not Found.

Answer (score -1):

Server=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;;**User ID**=xxxx_user;Password=xxxx;  where user id has a space in it as opposed to 
Server=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;;**UserID**=xxxx_user;Password=xxxx;   WRONG!!!!!!!
See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/ for confirmation.