# MVC - InvalidOperationException: UserId not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

When I register a user using the following code:

```
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I am able to access all of the views with the [Authorize] attribute.
However, if I log out and back in with the same user I get an error page with

> "InvalidOperationException: UserId not found"

The error seems to be coming from my SignInAsync function at the statement:

```
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

I am not adding a UserID and there is no UserId field in the user classs (its Id) or in the AspNetUsers table.
The user exists in that table, but again, there is no UserId.

I have tried clearing the cookies etc, but still no luck in re-logging in.
Am I doing the register wrong? I don't understand why the authentication is looking for the UserId field when it doesn't seem to exist

EDIT:
When I login the first time...i get the error page. However, when I reopen the page and it reads the cookie, I have access to everything. What the heck is going on with the initial login?

here is the SignInAsync method:

```
 private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            var _identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, _identity);
        }
```

**inclusion**:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your User model?

Comment: the User is an IPrinicipal implementation. i think its baked in. and the user object is an IdentityUser

Comment: Could you show us implementation of method SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);?

Comment: added. Thank you for your help, all

Comment: @rigamonk - You are showing two different `CreateIdentityAsync`. Which one are you referring to?

 You should also show what your `ApplicationUser` looks like as it may be related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/35017046/5233410.

Comment: The user in the provided link was using a custom login. I do not have a UserId. There are userId fields in the built in aspnet tables: AspNetUserRoles and AspNetUserRoles

Comment: @rigamonk. rereading your question. You say the issue is when you try to log back in. You showed the `Register` action where you use the `SignInAsync`. good. Can you show the Action used when the user logs in.

Comment: Two things:

1.) Please share your login action code as requested above.
2.) Do you have your Database Initializer set to `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I am wrong about you having mentioned Dapper, so the Dapper-specific details are not relevant, but the general idea of the fix remains - your Id and UserId columns are likely not getting matched up correctly.

---

I ran into this exact error yesterday.  I think you previously had mentioned that you're using Dapper as the data access mechanism.  I think that was perhaps relevant because you've also mentioned that the table has a `Userid` field, but your user class has an `Id` property.  I am guessing you may also have some code to assign a new `Guid` to the `Id` property if there's not one there.  Something like this:

```
public ApplicationUser()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

This combined with how Dapper mapping works may be messing you up since the `Id` field will wind up with that new `Guid` instead of the one it is supposed to be reading from the table.

In the below sample, Dapper is unable to assign the Id field of the `ApplicationUser` because the DB field is named differently than the property of the class.  But it will already have an Id value from its constructor.  This causes later calls to `FindByIdAsync()` and friends to fail.

```
public async Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
    ApplicationUser result = null;

    using (var conn = await GetOpenDBConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            // this query is bugged with Dapper because UserId does not
            // exist on ApplicationUser.
            var queryResults = await conn.QueryAsync<ApplicationUser>(
                "SELECT UserId, UserName, Email FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @UserName;",
                new { UserName = userName });

            result = queryResults.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                            //handle error appropriately.
            result = null;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

If it is in fact a Dapper mapping issue, you can either rename the field in the query results such as `SELECT UserId as [Id], UserName, Email FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @UserName`, or see [Randall Stutton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902674/manually-map-column-names-with-class-properties) for how to map Dapper fields in a really clean way.